# How to pass AWS AccountId in REST API's uri(Cloudformation)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Code:

```
  x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
    uri: "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:428377611111:function:${stageVariables.target_lambdaName}/invocations"
```

If use Pseudo Parameters like below i'm facing issue.

Updated Code:

```
 x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
    uri: "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:${AWS::AccountId}:function:${stageVariables.target_lambdaName}/invocations"
```

### Error:

```
Errors found during import: Unable to put integration on 'GET' for resource at path '/getMessage': Invalid HTTP endpoint specified for URI (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: 3da76bd8-d714-11e8-8ec4-4b324c6636a4)
```

Thanks in advance.

Naresh

Answer (score 0):

First, you should remove your AWS Account ID from the question.

If you're using a SAM Template YAML file and passing variables to your template during your pipeline stage via ParameterOverrides you should then have parameters declared at the top of the file in your SAM Template YAML file and your code should be as an example POST.

```
paths:
        /PATH_NAME:
          get:
            responses: {}
            x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
              uri:
                Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${FUNCTION_NAME_HERE.Arn}/invocations
              httpMethod: POST
              type: aws_proxy
```

This is assuming this piece of code is attached to:

```
Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
```

Without any other information I'm just assuming what you're trying to do.

As a side note, you can access your account id in CloudFormation like so:

```
${AWS::AccountId}
```

Comment: Chad-elias, Thanks for your response AWS resource type is AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi . I have tried with "Fn::Sub" still it's showing same error. Please check the code for your reference : https://github.com/Naresh4u/NestedCFT-POC/blob/master/NestedCFT-2/SwaagerConfigurationStack.yaml  -- Line : 46 

Thank you 
Naresh

Answer (score 0):

Use of Pseudo Parameters in the SAM AWS::Serverless::Api resource has been documented in this realworld SAM example Github https://github.com/awslabs/realworld-serverless-application/wiki/Amazon-API-Gateway#use-awsserverlessapi-in-your-cloudformation-template

The example using [AWS::Include](https://github.com/awslabs/realworld-serverless-application/blob/850ddf56764e59e1dd4ca2c40fd5bc8130061313/backend/sam/app/api.template.yaml#L32-L36) allows the use of Pseudo Parameters in the swagger file.